# Add H1/H2 Buttons to text editor in Wordpress CMS

Tags: wordpress

How can I add the option to format text as H1/H2 on the text editor in the CMS on the visual tab, I need buttons(i know its under format dropdown).

Answer (score 0):

You already have them. Look at the Format drop-down - as seen on this picture: [image]

You can alternatively press `Ctrl` + `1`, `Ctrl` + `1`, `Ctrl` + `2`, `Ctrl` + `3`, `Ctrl` + `4`, `Ctrl` + `5` or `Ctrl` + `6` to make the marked text a `h1`, `h2`, `h3`, `h4`, `h5` and `h6` respectively, or if you haven't marked any text to start typing in the corresponding heading tag.

Comment: Yes it is under format tab, but I need h1,h2 as buttons same as that of Bold and Italics.

Comment: I don't think it's supported by default. The only option I can think of would be to [Create a tinyMCE plugin](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Creating_a_plugin). Is it really that necessary to have them as buttons? I mean - it's up to you if you want to add a plugin to tinyMCE, but to me it seems like an unnecessary hassle, considering that the keyboard shortcuts can be even quicker than buttons.

Comment: Thats client requirement :(

Comment: Oh those clients... I hate them when they want things like that :D Well, look-up on how to make a plugin for tinyMCE and then see how to enable the plugin in the WordPress editor(info on filter [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE_Custom_Buttons#Enabling_hidden_MCE_buttons)).